# Blink Detection using dlib and opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, dlib

I have gotten this code from pyimagesearch and tried to run it but when i run the file i get these errors. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here? I have installed all the needed packages and libraries. All conda packages are up to date. Please look in to the error codes section and have a look if you can figure out what is wrong here.

```
    # USAGE
    # python detect_blinks.py --shape-predictor 
    shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat --video blink_detection_demo.mp4
    # python detect_blinks.py --shape-predictor 
      shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

# import the necessary packages
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2

def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
    # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])

    # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
    # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    # compute the eye aspect ratio
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    # return the eye aspect ratio
    return ear

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="",
    help="path to input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define two constants, one for the eye aspect ratio to indicate
# blink and then a second constant for the number of consecutive
# frames the eye must be below the threshold
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3
EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 3

# initialize the frame counters and the total number of blinks
COUNTER = 0
TOTAL = 0

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])

# grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the left and
# right eye, respectively
(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]

# start the video stream thread
print("[INFO] starting video stream thread...")
vs = FileVideoStream(args["video"]).start()
fileStream = True
# vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
# vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
# fileStream = False
time.sleep(1.0)

# loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
    # if this is a file video stream, then we need to check if
    # there any more frames left in the buffer to process
    if fileStream and not vs.more():
        break

    # grab the frame from the threaded video file stream, resize
    # it, and convert it to grayscale
    # channels)
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # detect faces in the grayscale frame
    rects = detector(gray, 0)

    # loop over the face detections
    for rect in rects:
        # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
        # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
        # array
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
        # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

        # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0

        # compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
        # visualize each of the eyes
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink
        # threshold, and if so, increment the blink frame counter
        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            COUNTER += 1

        # otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
        # threshold
        else:
            # if the eyes were closed for a sufficient number of
            # then increment the total number of blinks
            if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
                TOTAL += 1

            # reset the eye frame counter
            COUNTER = 0

        # draw the total number of blinks on the frame along with
        # the computed eye aspect ratio for the frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "Blinks: {}".format(TOTAL), (10, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

the errors are

```
usage: detect_blinks.py [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-v VIDEO]
detect_blinks.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape- 
   predictor
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2




%tb
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-55db51806586>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Rayhan/Downloads/Compressed/blink-detection/blink-detection/detect_blinks.py', wdir='C:/Users/Rayhan/Downloads/Compressed/blink-detection/blink-detection')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Rayhan/Downloads/Compressed/blink-detection/blink-detection/detect_blinks.py", line 39, in <module>
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1734, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1766, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 2001, in _parse_known_args
    ', '.join(required_actions))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 2393, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 2380, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)

SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: The error tells you what to do. When running your python program you have to pass a value to the --shape_predictor argument. So call your program like so
`python detect_blinks --shape-predictor PATH` and replace PATH with the path to facial landmark predictorr.

Comment: you need to to add the path of the shape_predictor.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code which works :

```html
import numpy as np  
import cv2  
import dlib  
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist  
   
PREDICTOR_PATH = "/home/erp-next/Downloads/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"  
   
# FULL_POINTS = list(range(0, 68))  
# FACE_POINTS = list(range(17, 68))  
   
# JAWLINE_POINTS = list(range(0, 17))  
# RIGHT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(17, 22))  
# LEFT_EYEBROW_POINTS = list(range(22, 27))  
# NOSE_POINTS = list(range(27, 36))  
RIGHT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(36, 42)) 
LEFT_EYE_POINTS = list(range(42, 48))  
# MOUTH_OUTLINE_POINTS = list(range(48, 61))  
# MOUTH_INNER_POINTS = list(range(61, 68))  
   
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.2 
EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 2  
frame_c=0   
COUNTER_LEFT = 0  
TOTAL_LEFT = 0  
   
COUNTER_RIGHT = 0  
TOTAL_RIGHT = 0  
   
def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):  
   # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of  
   # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates  
   A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])  
   B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])  
   
   # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal  
   # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates  
   C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])  
   
   # compute the eye aspect ratio  
   ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)  
   
   # return the eye aspect ratio  
   return ear  
   
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()  
   
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)  
   
# Start capturing the WebCam  
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
   
while True:
   global frame_c   
   print(frame_c)
   frame_c +=1
   ret, frame = video_capture.read()  
   
   if ret:  
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
   
     rects = detector(gray, 0)  
   
     for rect in rects:  
       x = rect.left()  
       y = rect.top()  
      #  x1 = rect.right()  
      #  y1 = rect.bottom()  
   
       landmarks = np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(frame, rect).parts()])  
   
       left_eye = landmarks[LEFT_EYE_POINTS]  
       right_eye = landmarks[RIGHT_EYE_POINTS]  
       
       left_eye_hull = cv2.convexHull(left_eye)  
       right_eye_hull = cv2.convexHull(right_eye)  
       cv2.drawContours(frame, [left_eye_hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)  
       cv2.drawContours(frame, [right_eye_hull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)  
   
       ear_left = eye_aspect_ratio(left_eye)  
       ear_right = eye_aspect_ratio(right_eye)  
   
       cv2.putText(frame, "E.A.R. Left : {:.2f}".format(ear_left), (300, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)  
       cv2.putText(frame, "E.A.R. Right: {:.2f}".format(ear_right), (300, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)  
   
       if ear_left < EYE_AR_THRESH:  
         COUNTER_LEFT += 1  
       else:  
         if COUNTER_LEFT >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:  
           TOTAL_LEFT += 1  
           print("Left eye winked")  
         COUNTER_LEFT = 0  
   
       if ear_right < EYE_AR_THRESH:  
         COUNTER_RIGHT += 1  
       else:  
         if COUNTER_RIGHT >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:  
           TOTAL_RIGHT += 1  
           print("Right eye winked")
         COUNTER_RIGHT = 0  
   
     cv2.putText(frame, "Wink Left : {}".format(TOTAL_LEFT), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)   
     cv2.putText(frame, "Wink Right: {}".format(TOTAL_RIGHT), (10, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 255), 2)  
   
     cv2.imshow("Faces found", frame)  
   
   ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)  
   
   if ch == ord('q'):  
     break  
   
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Above code uses "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" library which  plotes 68 predefine points on face.
using those points it will track eye and using euclidean distance algorithm it check if eye is blinked or not.

try this.

Comment: is it possible to detect blink without face? For example it the frame is cropped with only eyes what should i do to make it working? Thank you

Comment: No, it is not possible to detect the blink without face using  "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks" as it needs to plot all 68 points on the face detected. This is one of the drawback of this library which makes it slow as well.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Can you please suggest any other process ? like how it can be done?

Comment: @RayhanShowrov as per my knowledge "shape_predictor_68_face_landmark" is the only library available for blink detection. Rest of the other libraries only have eye detection.